# Apache load balancer down because one of app cannot connect to database

Tags: apache-2.4

I finished the setting for one Apache with 4 apps ( just call them: A, B,C and D). One day somehow A cannot talked to the Database, but A is not down, so A still received a lot of request. Because our Apache set as load balancer, since A received more and more request but cannot handle any request, so Apache send some request to B, C and D. Finally, Apache is down because more and more request come.

So, does anyone have any suggestion can change the Apache setting to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: PS: A is not down, A just cannot handle the request because cannot talk to database.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
Keep small timeout for mysql connection (say 500 ms) within A. This way request will be terminated faster.

Solution 2:
Whenever A catches a timeout exception it should set an environment variable that mysql is down and other request should fail gracefully displaying error message to user. You can check for mysql connection every 1 out of 100 request. Thus only 1 request will be waiting for mysql connection while 99 will terminate immediately. If any request successfully connects to mysql, it will update environmental flag and let other request pass through. You should also send yourself a mail for every such exception for quicker recovery.

Solution 3:
Try to find out bottleneck, is it memory limit reached, are there too many number of apache threads ? If you are running php behind apache, then be aware that apache loads php into memory for each request. Thus each request takes minimum of 25 MB. You may use php-fpm instead of php, this will give 100 times boost to number of request you server can currently handle, given there are no other bottlenecks.